# Safetkinter RuntimeError: Recursion Limit

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

So I've been trying to get a threadsafe adapter for tkinter (I'm using Python 3.3) to help with some of my projects. I stumbled upon a recipe called "safetkinter" (recipe [578153](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578153/)), which promises to route all gui calls to the main thread. I tried it out, but I am having problems with a RuntimeError that keeps sticking its head up and ruining my endeavors. I've tried various ways of fixing it with no luck. So... Does anyone here know the trick to getting this to work? (also, safetkinter makes use of the threadbox recipe, and the affinity recipe by dependence. I also believe that the affinity module is the culprit of this problem.)

The script I was using to test the module:

```
import safetkinter as tkinter

class Main(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self._setup()
        self.mainloop()

    def _setup(self):
        tkinter.Button(self, text='Push me!').pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Also, here is a link to the exception traceback taken from the console:
[Traceback](http://pastebin.com/gn4WMCFD)

Answer (score 0):

As I see at the example of safetkinter usage, the initialization should be done in another way. Here is a short working code based on your code and safetkinter example (Frame with a Button). You can extend and improve it:

```
import safetkinter as tkinter

class Main(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        root = cls.create_application_root()
        self = cls.setup_class_instance(root)
        root.mainloop()

    @staticmethod
    def create_application_root():
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.minsize(400, 340)
        root.title('Title')
        return root

    @classmethod
    def setup_class_instance(cls, root):
        instance = cls(root)
        instance.button = tkinter.Button(root, text='Push me!').pack()
        return instance

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main.main()
```